# insertUpdate is fired when focus has lost

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

I want to add a `documentListener` to a `textarea` in `initcomponents()` method.

This is my code:

```
txtAreaNot.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // text was changed
            textAreaSituation = "changed";
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // text was deleted
            textAreaSituation = "deleted";
        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // text was inserted
            textAreaSituation = "inserted";
        }
    });
```

Here is what i dont understand; why insertupdate is fired everytime focus lost in textarea? I dont insert or change anything on it.

Comment: what do you mean `focus lost` ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like something that should happen, so I suspect that if you post a minimal runnable example to demonstrate that behavior your chances of getting an answer that solves your problem would increase greatly; I'm afraid that right now they are next to 0 unless this is a known bug and someone has it in mind. It's even likely that while you write the example you figure out what was wrong by yourself (happened to me often).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. My mistake. I totally forgot to change the value of textAreaSituation after    `focusLost` event triggered. So it outputs the same value.